# I'm not able to import ChromeOption class in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not been able to import a class file from selenium 3.7.1 , although  I have this class in the refrence library(which I have configured in the build path)

Please assist.

Below is a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c141.png) of my IDE where I'm trying to do the run the code

```
package mrLogin;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions; //Getting exception in this line
public class Login {
public static String driverPath = "C:/auto/Mass_Retail_Auto/bin/mrLogin/";
public static WebDriver driver;
public static ChromeOptions options; 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    //options.AddExtension("C:/auto/Mass_Retail_Auto/bin/mrLogin/modheader 
2.1.2.crx");    
    System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
          driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
    }
    catch(Exception e ){ 
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally {
    driver.close();
    System.out.println("Browser closed!!!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the dot from the import. And next time post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Wanted to show that I get exception while importing the class

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium 3.0 or till 3.4 version which is the most stable one. You won't be facing any problem with those versions. My suggestion would be go for `3.0` version.